# How can i use same elastic search server for multiple port so data does not effect to each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rspec

Hi i'm working with rails on my staging machine there is 3 port and they are using same code and elastic search server for all port also same . while i run my build with rspec then test data base for all port is different but elastic search server is same , so my data effect on es server .
i want something like that for each port i can differentiate data on es server and no data overlap on es server

Comment: If you are using the same Elasticsearch instance then it will contain the same data. You could use different index names for each environment.

Comment: Hi Henrik thanks for suggestion can you more elaborate  , how can i use different index name for each environment

Comment: If it is possible to set an environment variable, it could be used as a prefix in the index names, e.g. dev_index, staging_index. It would be best to have production on a separate Elasticsearch instance.